# I want to select from two tables (a,b) which are related to each other through third table(c), but table a has a composite primary key

Tags: sql-server

I want to select from two tables (customers,machins) which are related to each other through third table(orders), but table a has a composite primary key

Table customers has primary key as

```
id
```

Table machins has a composite primary key with these two columns:

```
machinId
machineModel
```

And these two are related to table orders

```
Id(fk)
machine(fk)
machintype
```

I want to select from customers and machins all machines that a person has bought (orders)

My select command is

```
Select c.name, c.land, m.namemachin  
from orders o 
inner join customers c on c.id = o.id 
inner join machins m on o.machine = m.Id  
where c.name = 'karl' and m.machine = o.machintype
```

But it doesn't work

Can you please help me?

Comment: Is machintype in table orders the same domain as machineModel in table machins?

Comment: Yes it is the same  , but it is not a foriegn key.

Comment: once you try like this,
inner join Machine M on m.machinId=o.machine and m.machineModel=o.machintype . May be you should verify data which are not in resultset but are expected.

Comment: Thank you, I will try it, but I have a question, is there any problem with o.machinModel when it is not a foriegn key?  In your solution I mean.

Answer (score 0):

If your fetching is something related to string concatenation i.e to obtain all machines as string. I think you can use STUFF and FOR XML PATH.

Or else go through th below link it might help 
http://www.w3resource.com/sql/joins/using-a-where-cluase-to-join-two-tables-related-by-a-composite-primary-key-or-foriegn-key-pair.php

Answer (score 0):

If you have a composite primary key in table `machins` then both of that column should be available in table `orders` for a proper relation. Then only you can do a proper join this tables for a select query.

As per the discussion `m.machineModel  = o.machintype`
So please try this query

```
Select c.name, c.land, m.namemachin  
from orders o 
inner join customers c on c.id = o.id 
inner join machins m on m.machinId = o.machine
                    and m.machineModel  = o.machintype
where c.name = 'karl'
```

Comment: Thank you for you reply i have both of them in "order" table  as

Comment: Thank you for you reply. i have both of them in "order" table  as "machintype" which is the same column as " machineModel" in table " machins" and in table orders i have " machine" which is the same as "machinId " in table " machins" .... but just machine (order) is fk and in table machins two columns ( machinId , machinemodel ) are a composite pk....thank you for your attention

Comment: then you can use  *inner join machins m on o.machine = m.machinId  
                and  o.machintype = m.machineModel* , modified the answer plz chk.

Comment: I will try it, but  I have a question, no problem when o.machintype is not a fk? Appreciated

Comment: For this query, no problem. you can use this in JOIN clause to get actual related data, but it is good to relate both using the FK for data consistency.

Comment: I put it in where Clause but it still dont work.
where o.machintype = m.machineModel
 
and also in the join Phrase as you have suggested
join on ..... 
it seems that I must relate the columns to each other. and o.mchintyp be a fk.
it will be appreciated if you help me.
thanks

Comment: May be u should verify data wch r u expected to come